# Told to not come in to work until next week after only working about 20 hours so far

Tags: new-job

So I am in my early 30s and live in Florida. I have a BS degree in a IT field and have about 3 years of experience working since I graduated. I am also a honorably discharged veteran. I was the top employee at the 2 jobs I have worked at since graduated and am extremely driven and want to devote all my efforts to my job as I started late in the game and went in the military - did not graduate until I was around 30.

I did interview over the phone and was told to come in next day as they wanted me for the position and thought I was the best applicant by a long shot. I started working as a consultant and worked for about 5 days. The pay is not that good - at least since it is only a few dollars more than my previous job.

Although I am a very good worker and have not had any issues in either previous jobs I do have arrests from when 5-6 years ago. I had multiple DUI charges and a few minor charges (all misdemeanors) and nothing related to theft or anything that would say that I am not honest or a bad person etc. My credit is also not that good and I am working to get that improved as I did not realize how important the score is until getting out of the service and not being as responsible with payments/credit as I should have.

Anyways, I was given a pretty large list of tasks and was working each day for many hours even though it was originally stated as a part time position. However, the day after I signed the form for a background check, I spoke to the person who hired me, and they said to not come in until the next week (4 days) as they were going to be out of the country. I have also been in contact with another employee in the office and they seem the same as when I had been working in the office with them.

I am very worried at this point as I just sensed it odd that there was alot of tasks they wanted done ASAP and most were in the office - and then when asking if I should go into the office to work on these tasks for the next few work days, they said to just come in at the start of next week. The last thing I have heard is from the other person in the office who is still very nice and helpful and said to contact the person who hired me (main person in charge below owners) at the start of the next working week at a certain time early in the morning to see when they wanted me to come in again.

Sorry for long post - I tend to write alot, but I would like any feedback if anyone takes the time to read my situation. Thanks for your time if you did read this post. I just found this site and will spend some time reading other similar situations if I can find them on here.

-A Concerned new employee who just started a great job and worried I may be let go already even though I have not done anything wrong on the job

Comment: I am sorry if this is not the correct place to ask such a question - or if it does not seen like to be even a question. The question I guess would be should I be concerned based on what I had posted.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be concerned. There's nothing you can do, so you just wait. But you should probably be prepared for the worse. Look at the positive though. They've seen you work and they've seen you work hard. That increases the possibility of trying to make work if it comes back negative.  I'll be honest, the DUI's are a hard bias to overcome.  I hope it works out though.

Comment: Does your boss know about the history or are they going to find out through the background check? You've only been working for them a few days. Perhaps they want to be available/around when you're working until they know you better.

Comment: They would find out through background checks. She mentioned she would be doing a background check on the first day and I said that would be fine. I honestly was about to tell her about the arrests, but there was another person with us.  It was not an issue as I had no issues for the first jobs, but they were not nearly as good a company as this one. I am expecting the worst as someone said, but am hoping that maybe they just want to talk to me and see what happened etc.

Comment: I went to the owners residence (most expensive place I have been in while living in this state) the first day after being 'hired'. It went very well and he seemed to really like me alot. He also told me to learn a language that the company uses and could possibly be considered to do something with it down the road in the office. I am probably going to contact him directly and just get to the bottom of it before waiting until next week. He said to call/email whenever I wanted. Should I call him or send an email? Or wait until next week to speak with the person who interviewed/hired me?

Comment: Going over your immediate supervisor's head is usually not a good strategy, at least not until you have exhausted working with your supervisor. I think you should wait until next week.

Comment: I appreciate all of the feedback here honestly. I am pretty sure they are going to tell me I am done, or (I hope) they will let me stay after I explain what happened when I was in college (even though I was mid/late 20s in college as I was in military 4 years) and not making the best choices. I was told by friend to not make any excuses or blame anything else for what happened. She said I just need to 'own' everything myself and say that I have learned from that and I am moving forward etc. As you mentioned - same as military - use chain of command and don't jump over rank unless necessary

Comment: OK.  Not very clear here.  Are you an employee, or a consultant?  Do you understand the difference?

Comment: Since it was supposed to be part time could the problem be that they only budgeted something like 20hr/wk and you've already done that much this week?

Comment: @codenoir I honestly have never been a 'consultant' before and only an employee. I have also never heard of getting a new position and starting it before they already screened me prior to working. I will try looking up the differences as I did not know that it was a 'consulting' position and did not really know much about what that meant until now that I am in this situation

Comment: @LorenPechtel This could possibly be the issue as well (I hope very much) as it was discussed I would be working 10-20 hours per week and agreed that I would also be looking for a second FT or PT job as I would be seeking at least a 40+ hour workweek/compensation

Comment: You sound a little like you are panicking. Don't give the impression you are. If YOU are panicking about those arrests, they will be more likely to do the same If you are calm and open about it, it can be less of a red flag.

Comment: There is nothing you can do, so let go and let whatever happen, happen. If they are going to fire you because of something that happened 6 years ago, and something that you have served your punishment for, then they are not worth worrying about.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I don't want to lose this great opportunity and know I would do very well at the position. I spoke to the person who hired me this morning and she said she would 'see where we are at' and call me back this afternoon. It wasn't necessarily a bad call, but wasn't a confirmation that I will still be there =/

Comment: I was just let go as I suspected something was not right. The manager couldn't even tell me directly and was basically sounding like I am still connected somehow to the company but she was going to 'hold off' for now. My email pw was changed and Dropbox account I put alot of work into without being on the clock was also removed from my access.  I believe by law they need to tell me what actually caused them to change their mind. Very upsetting to say the least :(

Comment: Whenever you suspect you might be let go, make a copy of everything you can lose access to, for future reference. They probably can't tell you directly because they're determining what they legally **can** say and how to say it without violating any laws that would be discriminatory. I'm sorry this happened. Unfortunately, all you can really do is keep trying. Something will come along that will stick.

Comment: Could it be discriminatory? I have read that past arrests can disqualify you from positions, but I never heard of starting a job and working for 1.5 weeks, doing good/great work, and then be let go. The paperwork I signed does say the background check they did must be shown to be to make a final decision. I am planning on waiting a few days and then sending an e-mail requesting to know more about what transpired from Tues. of last week until today to go from such great things happening to we are going to 'hold off'. I have passed background checks before since then and thought it was a yes/no

Comment: http://www.amof.info/fcra.htm   By law, it says they must disclose the consumer report and let me know what it was that changed their decision. To just say I am not needed anymore after I started as part time thats insane to say now that I was only needed for 20 hours and thats it. I am going to contact someone at this agency and see what rights I have to what occurred, because this seems ridiculous and unprofessional to not tell me directly what occurred/changed overnight. Does anyone know about this or would this be a good question for the main section where I posted this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You already have done all you could by contacting the company.

You need to wait and see what eventuates. As a consultant you don't have a lot of recourses which is why consultants usually charge a lot more because they don't have the same job security and other benefits.

The situation does sound a bit disturbing, but don't let it worry you unduly until you have firm information.